# {Property evaluation failed.} when exporting data to excel in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel, epplus

I am using the code below to export records in a datatable to an excel file using EPPlus.

```
        Dim excelPackage = New ExcelPackage
        Dim excelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DemoPage")
        excelWorksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx")
        Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray())
        Response.End()
```

However, after walking through the code block, at Response.End(), I get an exception **{Property evaluation failed.}**

**Update:**
The error log is:

```
ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Reporting.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Reporting.aspx.vb:line 38
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line **Response.End()** and write the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.Buffer = True

Dim excelPackage = New ExcelPackage       
Dim excelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DemoPage")              

excelWorksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)        
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 

officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"         
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx")  
Response.Charset = ""
Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray())  
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
excelPackage.close() or
excelPackage=nothing or excelPackage.dispose() whichever is fit.

hope you will not get "Property Evaluation Error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

When Downloading file is tested in local machine Dont use 
    Response.End() ;
otherwise error can be thrown.

but Add
    Response.End() 
when the same code is deployed in server and test the same from client machine.
No error is thrown in this case.

Remove Response.Charset=""